# Is it possible to remove a Facebook application from the Page using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a facebook app.

The tab removes correctly, but is there a way to remove the application itself from page?

I supposed that the necessary info might be retrieved from the page settings and tried to get it using Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/%MY_PAGE_ID%/settings/?access_token=%VALID_TOKEN%

but it returns error: "(#210) Subject must be a page."

I've also tried to play with https://www.facebook.com/ajax/edit_app_settings.php
but it requires some unique variables which are generated by the facebook server and not available for the third side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing of application from Pages is not currently possible using Graph API (deprecated REST API missed this option too).

You only can remove `tab` (what you already do) from page. Once `tab` removed application will be available only on page settings and all links to `tab` of that application will point to page wall/landing tab.

Answer (score 0):

As an admin of the page you can add/remove/reorder the apps installed on your page via the API using a page access token- see [the Page documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) for more details.

If you're an admin of the app, but not of the page you won't be able to 'uninstall' your app from a page the same way, but the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) sent to your app will identify which page the app is being loaded from and you can choose not to show any content for the 'wrong' page